# How to solve this Twitter BootStrap issue on a simple page that have to run also on Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following problem: I have created this very simple HTML\CSS page that use the **Twitter BootStrap** CSS framework (this is putted into a JSP page but this is not important):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />" rel="stylesheet">



        <title>Login Page</title>

    </head>

    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="resources/img/logo2.png" class="logo">


        <div id="login-box">

            <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div class="error">${error}</div>
            </c:if>

            <form class="form-inline" name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                <input type='text' name='username' class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Nome Utente">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                <input type='password' name='password' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button> -->
              <input id="ricorda" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="login" />

              <br>

              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>

    <body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
        <div id="intestazione">
            <h1 align="center">WIFI e PNSD</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="login-box">

            <h3>Accesso al sistema</h3>

        </div>
         <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine in FireFox and in the last version of Explorer, the problem is that this page have to run fine also in **Internet Explorer 8** and trying with this browser I have many problem.

Using the IE developer tool and using the IE8 compatibility mode it seems that it can't see the **header** tag, why?

How can I try to solve this situation and correctly use BootStrap on IE-8?

Tnx

Comment: could you be more specific on what tag you mean?

Comment: @stack_bloom changed the original post, by the way it is the header tag

Answer (score 0):

Html5 is not supported in IE8, so you would have to "manually" add them in the DOM. You can use the following js, add it to your head. To read more about it you can do so in [this blogpost](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/)

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your header section:

```
 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: before  closing </header> tag in your website.

Comment: No, it seems can't work. What have I to obtain adding these lines?

Comment: just download those .js libraries and add them to your website. Its a good starting template which works: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: @AndreaNobili, the above said scripts by '@Daniel Ploskonka' renders properly when web page viewed in run time using server, or means viewing page on local may not render it correctly.